# throw own defined exception in visitor pattern java

Tags: java, exception, visitor-pattern

We  have to  write an app using the visitor design pattern  like ( https://www.baeldung.com/java-visitor-pattern ) , one example  element looks like, implementing interface Stmt :

```
public class Call implements Stmt {
    int hash_id;
    private String id;
    public Call(String id )   { this.id = id;}


    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        System.out.println("call.accept");
        v.visit( this);
    }

    public String getId () {  return id;}
    ....}
```

The vistor Interface  looks like this  code below , I may not change the  interface  code.

```
public interface Visitor {
    ... 
    ...

    void visit(Subroutine subroutine);

    void visit(Call call);
}
```

Inside the  Implementation  of an  Visitor (AbstractVisitor class) I have to throw a "UndefinedSubroutineException if the id (type string)  of a call class is not yet  existing  in the hashtable SubBefehle.
The existing  code with try catch statemenets never send as an exception  to my testcase ....

```
public abstract class AbstractVisitor implements Visitor {
.....
 private Hashtable<String, Integer> SubBefehle = new Hashtable< String, Integer>();

@Override
public void visit(Call call)  {
    ///  implementation work :

       try {

           IsFunctionNameExisting(call.getId());
       }
       catch (UndefinedSubroutineException e){
          // throw new UndefinedSubroutineException("");
       }
}

public void IsFunctionNameExisting(String fctname) throws UndefinedSubroutineException {
    boolean IsFound = false;

    if (SubBefehle.containsKey(fctname)) {
        System.out.println("Abstract visitor :  function name found -> PASS  ");
        IsFound = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Abstract visitor : function name not yet found -> EXCEPTION ");
         throw new UndefinedSubroutineException(" function name not found in function name list !");
    }
```

if the call IsFunctionNameExisting(call.getId()) is false if the name is not found inside the hash table. My optional solution is also not working .

```
///  optional solution 
@Override
public void visit(Call call) throws UndefinedSubroutineException  {
    ///  implementation work :
           IsFunctionNameExisting(call.getId());
       }
```

the corresponding testcase looks like this :

```
@Test 
public void testUndefinedSubroutine() {
    try {
        PROG_TEST.accept(testVisitor);
        fail("Exception expected");
    } catch (UndefinedSubroutineException e) {
       ........
    }
}
```

package turtle.logo;

the defintion  of UndefinedSubroutineException goes like  this :

```
public class UndefinedSubroutineException  extends Throwable {

    public  UndefinedSubroutineException (String message) {

        super(message);
    }
}
```

PS:  I can't  change the test cases and the interface  definition  &
I hope someone can help us with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `UndefinedSubroutineException` a RuntimeException. In that case since it is an unchecked exception, and you will not have to change your method signature.

Inside your test case you can now add a try catch block to handle the scenario.

Comment: how to rework UndefinedSubroutineException code , can you please advise ? testcase code II#m not allowed  change

Comment: Go to your `UndefinedSubroutineException` class and change it to 
`public class UndefinedSubroutineException extends RuntimeException`. 

You do not need to change anything else in your code.
Inside the test case `catch (UndefinedSubroutineException e)` block, you can now just write the logic of what you want to do if the Exception is caught.